# Pad 2 digits to the left of decimal and 1 to right

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

As per the below mock, **Temperature** should have

- minimum 2 digits to the left of decimal
- exactly 1 digit to the right of decimal

Eg:

`31.105` should be `31.1`

`2` should be `02.0`

```
  cityDetails = {
    city: "chennai",
    country: "india",
    weather: [
      {
        date: "Aug 3, 2018",
        temperature: 2,
        weather_name: "sunny",
        weather_image: "some image url"
      }
    ]
  };
```

Below is the code which I tried,

```
  transform(cityDetails) {

    this.temp = cityDetails.weather[0].temperature.toString().replace(
      /\d+/g,
      function pad(digits) {
        return digits.length === 1 ? '0' + digits : digits;
      });
  }
```

But it dosen't work as expected. Link to my https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wc8vu1

Comment: If you're using Angular, why not use the existing [number pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see the working blitz here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-8dhh12?file=src/app/app.component.ts

```
transform(cityDetails) {
   let pad = (digits) => digits.split('.')[0].length === 1 ? '0' + digits : digits;
   this.temp = pad(cityDetails.weather[0].temperature.toFixed(1));
}
```

A better way to do it using `number` pipe is https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kzkne3?file=src/app/app.component.html

```
{{temp | number:'2.1'}}
```

Comment: Thanks, I never know pipe can be used here.

Comment: sure, happy to help